# Manhwa where partway through a child is sacrified by terrorists in an attempt to assassinate the main character using bombs

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's one of those hunter manhwa where the main character has some kind of system and becomes overpowered. The event was around chapter 30 where the main character takes a trip to a middle eastern country. He observes some children playing when one of them approaches him. The child is blown up and the main character is unscathed. Out of anger for the dead children, the main character starts an all-out attack on the group who attacked him and wipes them out. It may or may not have also had a necromancer gimmick.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found it, *[Seoul Station's Necromancer](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147490/Seoul_Stations_Necromancer)*.

[image: Front cover of Seoul Station's Necromancer]

> After years of fighting for survival on planet Alphen, Kang Woojin had become a fearsome necromancer and ruler of his own territory. But now that he's finally found a way back to Earth, he's nothing more than a low-level player clearing dungeons for cash. Soon enough, though, Woojin's undeniable skills have major guilds vying for his attention. And just in time, because with Woojin's old enemy threatening invasion, those skills might be the only thing standing between humanity and destruction!

[The original webnovel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40602110) has been [licensed through Wuxia World](https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/seoul-stations-necromancer):

> When former high school student Kang Woojin finds himself returned back to Earth after being forcibly summoned to a foreign planet for 20 years, he soon finds that Earth is not the same, normal place as he once remembered it to be.
>
> With his former strength and age reset back to zero, watch Kang Woojin as he gets back on the path to becoming the Earth’s strongest Necromancer!

Comment: Hey, it's great that you found it.  Could you leave some additional details for us, like where to find it, the official blurb/synopsis, maybe some links?